# Parse getting blocked due to multiple queries.

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im using the Parse SDK, and at times, after running a few queries one after the other, all calls to Parse just get blocked and I need to restart my app. ( Log: http://pastebin.com/qk6jvtBb )

Usually a single operations involves these FOUR things: Save Object; Make Query; Save Installation; Send Push (im gonna keep the code really specific)

```
...
pObject.saveEventually();
...
pQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
...
pInstall.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() 
...
pPush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback()
```

What I want to know is. Should I use `sendInBackground` for all or `saveEventually` for all or should I run each in a separate `Runnable` with its own `Handler`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if all of the operations are specific to one task, then put it all in an IntentService, do nothing in the background.

so your code would look like this

```
    public class MyClass extends IntentService
    {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent mIntent) 
        {
            try
            {
               pObject.save();
               pQuery.getFirst();
               pInstall.save()
               pPush.send();
            }

            catch(ParseException e)
            {
               //handle errors here DEBUG
            }
       }
    }
```

The benefit to doing this is that your parse operations are executed one at a time, sequentially, and on a background worker thread. You won't have to worry about four/five different parse sdk calls running at the same time.

Remember, put the IntentService in the manifest. Start the IntentService with an Intent. No need to call stopSelf() when you are finished with your parse sdk operations. You will have to bind the service to your activity, or send a broadcast to let the activity or fragment know that the operation is complete.